# How Can I use several line break in a setText() method?

Tags: android

How Can I use  several line break in a `setText()` method? For example I wrote the following simple code and I want to see each number in a separate line as follows:

```
0
1
2
.
.
.
9
10
```

I used from a `for(int i=0; i=10; i++)` but when I run the following code as the result only I see the `10` value in the `textView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
         textView.setText(String.valueOf(i) + "\n"); // I see only the 10 value in the textView object.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting the text property of the TextView with each for loop iteration.  Instead, do something like this:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(i) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int  i =0;i<10;i++){
        sb.append(i+"\n");  
    }
    textView.setText(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

String text = "";

for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
    text += String.valueOf(i) + "\n"
}


textView.setText(text);
```